# Disabling alternate listboxes when clicking on alternate radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I have working is 2 radio buttons and one listbox. When the first radio button is clicked, the listbox is disabled but when the second radiobutton is clicked, the listbox is available. I now have to modify the app to have two listboxes and 3 radiobuttons. If the first radio-button is clicked, I need both listboxes disabled. If the second radiobutton is clicked, I need only the first listbox to be disabled. If the third radio-button is selected, I need only the second listbox to be disabled. I have no idea how to begin to do this in Javascript or JQuery! Any help would be very appreciated!! (I'm working in ColdFusion if that is relevant).

This is the code I have working right now. I have to add one more radiobutton and another listbox to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_radio()
{
if(document.MedicaidResidents.choice[1].checked){
document.getElementById("T1").disabled=true;
}else {
document.getElementById("T1").disabled=false;
}
}
</script>


<form name="MedicaidResidents" action="Medicaid_Residents.cfm"  method="post" id='f1'>

<input type="radio" name="choice" value='1' onClick="check_radio()";>States<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value='2' onClick="check_radio()";>Houses

<select name="stateprompt1" multiple="multiple" size="10" id="T1">
    <option value="" selected> -Select States- </option>
    <cfloop query="Medicaid_States">
        <option value="#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#">#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#</option>
    </cfloop>
</select>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your code is working can you just copy and paste the radio buttons and listbox you already have? if so this could work.

```
<form name="MedicaidResidents" action="Medicaid_Residents.cfm" method="post" id='f1'>

<input type="radio" name="choice" value='1' onClick="check_radio()";>States<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value='2' onClick="check_radio()";>Houses
<input type="radio" name="choice" value='3' onClick="check_radio()";>Foo

<select name="stateprompt1" multiple="multiple" size="10" id="T1">
<option value="" selected> -Select States- </option>
<cfloop query="Medicaid_States">
    <option value="#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#">#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#</option>
</cfloop>
</select>
<select name="stateprompt2" multiple="multiple" size="10" id="T2">
<option value="" selected> -Select States- </option>
<cfloop query="Medicaid_States">
    <option value="#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#">#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#</option>
</cfloop>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check_radio()
{
if(document.MedicaidResidents.choice[1].checked)
{
document.getElementById("T1").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("T2").disabled=true;
}
else if (document.MedicaidResidents.choice[2].checked)
{
document.getElementById("T1").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("T2").disabled=false;
}
else if (document.MedicaidResidents.choice[3].checked)
{
document.getElementById("T1").disabled=false;
document.getElementById("T2").disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Josh, thank you very much!! With just a little modification, it worked perfectly!!

Comment: no problem, if the answer was correct and you are content with it please mark it  as "correct/answered" the check mark by the number between the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below jsfiddle as well as the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj85/3jy0crdx/

There are many solutions for this.

My solution is using JQuery to disable based on radio button selection. And highlight with red background when the list box is disabled.

**HTML Code:**

```
 <form name="myForm" action="Medicaid_Residents.cfm" method="post" id='f1'>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" checked> States
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2"> Houses
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3"> Other
  </div>

  <div>
    <p> List Box 1 </p>
    <select name="stateprompt1" multiple="multiple" size="10" id="T1">
      <option value="" selected> -Select States- </option>
      <cfloop query="Medicaid_States">
        <option value="#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#">#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#</option>
      </cfloop>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p> List Box 2 </p>
    <select name="stateprompt2" multiple="multiple" size="10" id="T2">
      <option value="" selected> -Select States- </option>
      <cfloop query="Medicaid_States">
        <option value="#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#">#Medicaid_States.cStateCode#</option>
      </cfloop>
    </select>
  </div>

</form>
```

**JS:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var all_radio_buttons = document.myForm.choice;
  var prev = null;
  var selected_radio_value = "1";
  doRefresh(selected_radio_value);

  for (var i = 0; i < all_radio_buttons.length; i++) {
    all_radio_buttons[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.value);
      selected_radio_value = this.value;
      doRefresh(selected_radio_value);

    };
```

**CSS Code:**

```
form#f1 > div {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form#f1 > div > select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

form#f1 > div > select[disabled] {
  background: red;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks Manoj!

Comment: Please feel free mark the answer as correct if it helps. Cheers!!